# how transform c codes like that to mysql stored procs

Tags: mysql

C codes:

```
unsigned int HashValue(const char *str)
{
    const char *p = str;
    unsigned int hashValue = 0;
    while( *p != '\0' )
    {
        hashValue += *(unsigned char*)p;
        ++p;
    }
    return hashValue;
}
```

My Answer:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE `test`.`HashValue`(IN str CHAR(32))
BEGIN
    SET @size = LENGTH(str);
    SET @pos = 1;
    SET @hashValue = 0;
    WHILE @pos<@size+1 DO
        SET @nCh = SUBSTRING(str,@pos,1);
        SET @hashValue = @hashValue + ASCII(@nCh);
        SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT @hashValue;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But:

```
set @str;
call HashValue(@str);
```

while `@str` is English is ok,but change to other wide byte language(just like chinese) it works wrong;

I know the problem is the function `SUBSTRING()`,the second parameter is not steadily increase by one byte.

remark:
mysql is utf_8 code

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary blank lines in your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE `test`.`HashValue`(IN str CHAR(32))
    BEGIN

        SET @pos = 1;
        SET @hashValue = 0;
        SET @szHex = HEX(str);
        SET @size = LENGTH(@szHex);
        WHILE @pos<@size+1 DO
            SET @cCh = SUBSTRING(@szHex,@pos,2);
            SET @nCh =CAST(ASCII(UNHEX(@cCh)) AS UNSIGNED);
            SET @hashValue = @hashValue + @nCh;
            SET @pos = @pos + 2;
        END WHILE;

        SELECT @hashValue;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Just use `HEX` and `UNHEX`.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Polite way of saying "format your code please, read the faq". Gets boring after the first few hundred times.